# Pyinstaller missing bootloader

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I fresh installed Python37-32 on win10-64
All requirements seem to be satisfied and my hello world python file is executing

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print("hello world")
```

However when I try to use pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller hello.py
```

It finishes with error

```
5764 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
5764 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\xxxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run_d.exe
5764 INFO: checking EXE
5764 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
5779 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc

Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your
platform. For more details and instructions how to build the bootloader see
<https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bootloader-building.html>
```

It is a basic installation on windows, I should not have to recompile any bootloader manually (I am used to pyinstaller with older python versions and never had problems).
Where should I look to solve this issue ?

**EDIT**

The error shows up in python37-32 but not in python37 (64bits)

Comment: Well how did you install pyinstaller?

Comment: @RvdK `python -m pip install pyinstaller`
I also tried with the development version. Same effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases) and install from source instead using pip.

```
python setup.py install
```

Then if your system is 64bit, the 64bit bootloader is built altough the python37-32 needs 32 bit bootloader.
In the source `cd bootloader` and run `python ./waf all --target-arch=32bit` as explained [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5/bootloader-building.html)

Then copy `run.exe` from build folder to pyinstaller 32bit bootloader folder.

An [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4318) has been opened on pyinstaller github.

Comment: Short bus here: I see now, so you download this unzip, navigate to bootloader, compile the bootloader for your target `python ./waf all --target-arch=32bit`, then run `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure that you are running the latest version of Pyinstaller==3.5.
The previous versions of pyinstaller do not support python3.7.

If that is okay, it could be because of an incomplete installation of pyinstaller
Check manually if the bootloader files are present for your pyinstaller installation. The bootloader (pre-compiled) files should be in your python installation

```
c:\users\xxxxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run_d.exe
```

As a last resort, I would suggest installing pyinstaller through setup.py. It should build the bootloader for your machine when you run setup.py
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/installation.html#installing-from-the-archive

Comment: `Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit` contains `run.exe` `run_d.exe` `runw.exe` `runw_d.exe` and  `Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit` only the `runw_d.exe` So I suppose the booltoader has not been built by pip during installation

Comment: I cannot say for sure, because I am not familiar with the exact names of the executables built by the bootloader. But I think it is worth investigating lower versions of PyInstaller

Comment: It seems installing with pip or source gives same result. On 64bit machine, the 64bit bootloader is generated (even if you use 32bit python version). No I have an explication but problem not solved

Comment: Not sure if it going to help, but when you are installing it through source, you can manually delete the already compiled bootloader files. Then python will build them for you

Comment: Correct. And as it detects 64bit windows it doesn't build 32bit bootloader (if my understanding is correct)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did this:

```
pip uninstall PyInstaller
pip install PyInstaller
```

Here's what happened: It worked!!!